# isnull with multiple, specified columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,'a','b'],'b':[1,np.nan,3],'c':['x','y','z']})

     a    b  c
0  NaN  1.0  x
1    a  NaN  y
2    b  3.0  z
```

I would like to select all rows where both columns 'a' and 'b' are nulls so I get this:

```
     a    b  c
2    b  3.0  z
```

I know I can do this:

```
df.loc[(pd.isnull(df['a'])) & (pd.isnull(df['b']))]
```

...but my actual data has many specific columns I need to use with `isnull`. 
Is there a more efficient way to do this where I can specify columns 'a' and 'b' in a list somehow (for example)?

Answer (score 2):

We can check `dropna`

```
df.dropna(subset=['a','b'],thresh=2)
Out[96]: 
   a    b  c
2  b  3.0  z
```